# How can I tell a function enters kernel or not

Tags: c, kernel

I am implementing a program to run in user space as often as possible. So I am trying to call functions which enter and leave kernel space as less as possible. For example, I use some DMA API which read/write but bypass the kernel.

I don't know how to tell a function needs to enter kernel space or not. For example, I want to call `getenv()` to get environment variables set by the host, but worrying it may pass my program and enter the kernel space. I cannot find this imformation from man pages. Here is the man page of [`getenv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html).

Comment: The information returned by `getenv()` is not stored in kernel space, so it won't make the transition to the kernel.  However, I don't know that there's a simple way to make that determination from manual pages, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Does this mean whether a function enters kernel space is a dynamic behavior?

Comment: Probably, more or less — at least, in the sense that `getchar()`, for example, will usually not enter kernel space (when there is data still to be read in the buffer), but will sometimes enter the kernel (when there is no data left in the buffer).  So, this is dynamic behaviour.  Other functions (`getpid()`, for example) will always enter the kernel.  It depends on the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you run your program through strace?  That will let you know where you are making system calls that will enter kernel space

Comment: Thanks. I just known strace from you. So, there is no documentation saying which enters the kernel and which not? We need to run it. Does this mean whether a function enters kernel space is a dynamic behavior?

Comment: have you tried "man strace" :)  If you don't have access to it, here is an online version of the manpage: http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace

Comment: strace produces a lot of output that can look intimidating if you're not used to it, and there aren't many great tutorials on it.  Take a look at this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-strace.html

Comment: Anything shown by strace is entry/exit from kernelspace. strace does not show any activity for purely-userspace operations.

Comment: Correct, but isn't this what he wanted: "I don't know how to tell [if]  a function needs to enter kernel space or not"

Answer (score 0):

I thinks most IO functions will cause your program to the kernel? 
Maybe you should check the system APIs that used by you

Comment: I don't know where to check. For example, this is the ``getenv()`` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html page, I cannot tell whether it enters kernel space or not.